# Crear Hash con un Vector en Rust

Tags: rust

¿como podria hacer un hash en formato de vector, con un vector de bytes? (sin la libreria crypto-hash)

Yo tengo un vector u8 con bytes y necesitaria un vector u8 con sha256 .

```
use sha2::{Sha256, Digest};

pub trait Hashable {
    fn bytes (&self) -> Vec<u8>;

    /// NEED TO IMPLEMENT THE HASH
    fn hash (&self) -> Vec<u8>{
        let mut hasher = Sha256::new();
        hasher.update(&self.bytes);
        let result = hasher.finalize();
        println!("{:?}", result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use sha256::digest_bytes;

fn vector_to_sha256(vector: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let val: String = digest_bytes(&vector).to_owned();
    let result: Vec<u8> = val.into_bytes();
    return result;
}

pub trait Hashable {
    fn bytes (&self) -> Vec<u8>;
    fn hash (&self) -> Vec<u8>{
        vector_to_sha256(self.bytes())
    }
}
```